# why calling these 'algebra' and 'ring' too?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question, terminology

In measure theory you have 'algebra's' and 'rings' as subsets of the powerset of the underlying set of the measurable space. If I am well informed then you speak of an algebra if it is closed under finite union and complement, and of a ring if complement is interchanged here by difference. My question:

> Is there a connection between these concepts and the well-known algebra's and rings in algebraic theory?

In fact I don't think so, but - if I am right in this - then why are these terms used in this context?

Comment: The mention of measure theory suggests you are thinking of Boolean and/or sigma-algebras.  The Boolean ring does have operations that satisfy the axioms of a ring, in the conventional abstract algebra sense.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you. Indeed sigma-algebras are algebras closed under countable union in this context. Can you define Boolean algebra for me? Uptil now I haven't encountered them in measure theory.

Comment: I think you should take a look at Stone duality. There´s an adjunction between Boolean spaces and Boolean rings.

Comment: @user40276 Well, that is completely new to me, but I will dive into it. Your comment has the 'smell' of categories, and I like these. Thanks for your tip.

Comment: Note this old Question at MathOverflow, [terminology about ring/algebra in abstract algebra and measure theory](http://mathoverflow.net/q/22676/10700), which has Comments pointing to the use of these terms in Halmos's 1950 book *Measure Theory*.  I can check it out from my local university library (Google Books only gives a snippet view) and provide what he has to say about the terminology, if that would be of interest.

Comment: @hardmath Your comment was very helpful. Thank you also for your offer to check it out from local university library. However, don't bother. The importance of my question is toolimited for that.

Answer (score 0):

An algebra in measure theory is a class, say '$\alpha$', closed under all finite set operations, you can have $\sigma$-algebras, which can be also called $\sigma$ rings as they hold connective laws. So yes to your question as long as you allow for countable unions only.

Comment: I know that linguistically algebra is connected with calculation using letters, but that is not my question. What you are saying about rings does not make sense to me.

Comment: If the down-votes could be clarified, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The downvotes (and the comment by the OP) are probably for the original version of your answer. If I'd seen that answer, I'd also have downvoted it.

Comment: @Magdiragdag My roommate was on, so I had to edit it out. My answer apparently helped the asker, based on "Indeed sigma-algebras are algebras closed under countable", may my downvotes be reversed?

Comment: @user137849 I just try to clarify why there were downvotes.

Comment: @user137849 I would like to point out that the edit history is visible - I don't know if you can see it, but I surely can.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I understand that, I would just like the downvotes to be reversed based on the apparent helpfulness of the answer.

Comment: @user137849 I think you can only hope the downvoters happen to visit again.

Comment: @Magdiragdag Alright, I will rely on that. Thank you for your support!

Comment: Your Answer is not as preposterous as before, but I think it only a relative improvement.  Do you wish to give further information?